# Karma closure gives "Missing Dependency" error even for the demo app

Tags: karma-runner

I am trying to make karma closure plugin work for me.

I did all the changes mentioned here.

```
https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-closure
```

But i am unable to resolve the dependencies for the goog.

I did all exact steps there in the example. 
So i cloned the whole repo and trying running the

```
karma start test-app/karma.config.js
```

Karma for the repo is also failing for me. it doesn't find "goog.string"
Shows the error here:

```
https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-closure/blob/master/lib/resolver.js#L37
```

It will be great to if someone can help with this.

Thanks.